# How to do a ?. None check

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this is in the pipeline for Java 8 or 9 but I think there must be a way to do this in python. Say for example I am writing a complex expression and cannot be bothered to add null checks at all levels (example below)

```
post_code = department.parent_department.get('sibling').employees.get('John').address.post_code
```

I dont want to worry about several intermediate values being 'None'. For example if the parent_department does not have a sibling key I want to shunt and return None assigned to post_code. Something like

```
post_code = department?.parent_department?.get('sibling')?.employees?.get('John')?.address?.post_code
```

Can this be done in Python 2.7.1? I know this means more trouble while debugging but assume I have done all pre-checks and if any value is null it means an internal error so it is enough if I just get the error trace that the particular line failed.

Here is a more verbose way. I just need a one-liner that does not throw random exceptions

```
def get_post_code(department):
    if department is None:
        return None
    if department.parent_department is None:
        return None
    if department.parent_department.get('sibling') is None:
        return None
    ... more checks...
    return post_code = department.parent_department.get('sibling').employees.get('John').address.post_code
```

Comment: It is not clear what types of objects these are. In a dictionary, `.get()` is a method, so you'd call it with `.get('sibling')`, *not* use indexing `(.get['sibling'])`, which would return a `KeyError`. You already would get `AttributeError` or `KeyError` exceptions if anything in that list returned `None` or did not exist.

Comment: Fixed the ( bracket. Assume syntaxes are correct. I just dont want a key error or Attribute error or a null error. I basically want post_code to be null if any of the internal structure is not what I expect

Answer (score 2):

If you want `post_code` to be `None` then catch the exceptions raised by trying to access non-existing items:

```
try:
    post_code = department.parent_department.get('sibling').employees.get('John').address.post_code
except (AttributeError, KeyError):
    post_code = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually one valid answer for this is to start thinking in terms of Monads (may-be monads) to chain these functions. A very primitive tutorial is at https://github.com/dustingetz/dustingetz.github.com/blob/master/_posts/2012-04-07-dustins-awesome-monad-tutorial-for-humans-in-python.md